# fetch all partition keys in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I have a high load of data (~ 50 mil per minute) this is how my table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE test.metric (
    key text,
    timestamp bigint,
    value double,
    PRIMARY KEY (key, timestamp) )
```

I need to get all unique `key` . I can do of course `SELECT DISTINCT key from metrics;` but I was wondering if there is more efficient way (besides creating another table that contains only the keys) to fetch all distinct partitions  keys (maybe from some cassandra table)

Comment: Curious - had you created a new table to keep track of keys, wouldn't you have to then worry about consistency? Eg. say you add the metric but addition of key in the new table fails. Then you'll have to roll back but Cassandra doesn't do rollback

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is setup a set of parallel jobs that each execute:

`SELECT DISTINCT key FROM metrics WHERE token(key) >= ? AND token(key) < ?`

Then divide up the ring (you're probably using Cassandra's Murmur3 partitioner, so you'll go from -2^63 to 2^63) into as many sections as is reasonable, and issue those queries in parallel. You can use the output of `nodetool ring` to help give you some hints on dividing up the jobs - breaking it down by host so you only have a smallnumber of SELECT queries running per host may be most performant.

Comment: thank you. that it's interesting. can you elaborate ? is'n creating multiple queries might end with duplicate keys ?

Comment: I was just reading about this technique! see here for more explanation: http://www.scylladb.com/2017/02/13/efficient-full-table-scans-with-scylla-1-6/